# WordPress WP_Query - date_query not working with timestamp

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to do a date query in a WP_query to only return posts from after a timestamp.

I have this so far...

```
$timestamp = '1549103038';

$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'       => -1,
        'fields'              => 'ids',
        'date_query'     => array(
            'after' => $timestamp
        ),
    );
```

But this is giving me all of my posts, it is ignoring the date_query for some reason.